# Composition of two symmetric relations

Tags: relations, function-and-relation-composition

Let $R1$, $R2$ be symmetric relations on a set. I want to prove that $R1\circ R2$ is symmetric if and only if $R1\circ R2=R2\circ R1$.

I have tried a few problems of this type by doing something like this:

$(a,b) \in R2 \implies (b,a) \in R2$.
 Also $(b,c) \in R1 \implies (c,b) \in R1$.

Let $R1 \circ R2(a)=R1(b)=c$. So $(a,c) \in R1\circ R2$ and $(c,a) \in R1\circ R2.$

But in this problem, I am unable to proceed.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\circ$ is a relation, what does it mean to write $R1\circ R2=R2\circ R1$?

Comment: @abiessu - $\circ$ is not a relation.  If $R\subset X\times Y$ and $S\subset Y\times Z$ then $R\circ S=\{(x,z)\in X\times Z:\textrm{for some }y\in Y, xRy\textrm{ and }ySz\}$.

Comment: Here, $\circ$ is the composition of relations. By $R1\circ R2 = R2 \circ R1$, I mean $R1$ applied on a set (say $X$) after applying $R2$ should give same result as $R2$ applied on $X$ after applying $R1$.

Comment: My fault for misunderstanding, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write out the definitions:

$R_1\circ R_2=R_2\circ R_1$ means that for every $x,y_1,z$ such that $(x,y_1)\in R_1$ and $(y_1,z)\in R_2$, there exists $y_2$ such that $(z,y_2)\in R_1$ and $(y_2,x)\in R_2$.

$R_1\circ R_2$ is symmetric means that if $(x,z)\in R_1\circ R_2$ then $(z,x)\in R_1\circ R_2$.  This in turn means that for every $x,y_1,z$ such that $(x,y_1)\in R_1$ and $(y_1,z)\in R_2$, there exists $y_2$ such that $(z,y_2)\in R_1$ and $(y_2,x)\in R_2$.

Can you see why these two properties are equivalent?

[Note: this shows that $R_2\circ R_1$ is the *converse* or *inverse* relation to $R_1\circ R_2$; i.e., $(x,z)\in R_1\circ R_2$ if and only if $(z,x)\in R_2\circ R_1$.  If you can show this (which is fairly easy from the definition of relation composition) then you can solve the problem very quickly and neatly, since a relation is symmetric if and only if it equals its converse.]

Comment: This can be explicited as well using matrices: see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4303954) mentionning the question of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

A possible follow up to the existing answer, but little more in detail:

$$\begin{aligned}\boxed{\Leftarrow:}\quad R_1\circ R_2&=R_2\circ R_1\\ (x,y)&\in R_1\circ R_2\\&\implies \exists z,(x,z)\in R_2\land (z,y)\in R_1\\&\overset{R_1,R_2\text{symmetric }}{\implies} (z,x)\in R_2
\land (y,z)\in R_1\\&\implies (y,x)\in R_2\ \circ R_1=R_1\circ R_2\\&\implies R_1\circ R_2\text{ is symmetric }\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}\boxed{\Rightarrow: }&\color{white}\implies R_1\circ R_2\text{ is symmetric }\\
&\implies R_1\circ R_2=(R_1\circ R_2)^{-1}=R_2^{-1}\circ R_1^{-1}\\&\overset{R_1,R_2\text{ symmetric}}{=}R_2\circ 
R_1\end{aligned}$$