# Proving that composition of symmetric relations is symmetric

Tags: relations, function-and-relation-composition

If $S$ and $R$ are both symmetric relations with the same domain, will $S\circ R$ also be symmetric?

I think it should be symmetric. If $S$ and $R$ are both symmetric, then there should be a $x,y$ $\in$ $S$, such that $xSy$ and $ySx$ are true. Also, there should be a $x,z$ $\in$ $R$, such that $xSz$ and $zSx$, combined them together, we get $y$ $S\circ R$ $z$ and $z$ $S\circ R$ $y$ are also true, so $S\circ R$ should be symmetric.
I didn't know if this is the right proof or not. Please help...

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Oh, and to get the \circ thing to work you need to put it in "math mode" by encircling it with dollar signs. So, `S\circ R` will yield "S\circ R", but `$S\circ R$` produces $S\circ R$ which is what you want. See here for more details: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What are $S$ and $R$ ?

Comment: Thank you guys for editing the format for me and letting me know what is a proper way to ask questions. ;-)

Comment: @Griboullis A relation like $R$ and $S$ between $n$ elements is nothing else than a $n \times n$ boolean array/matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general :

$R$ and $S$ have to fullfill condition $S \circ R = R \circ S$.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/498903).

Besides, a powerful approach is to use the representation of relations by their matrix, using for composition a particular multiplication rule denoted by $\odot$ (ordinary multiplication followed by a thresholding operation in order that entries $>1$ are set equal to $1$). This is well explained [here](http://www.facweb.iitkgp.ac.in/%7Eniloy/COURSE/Autumn2008/DiscreetStructure/scribe/Lecture07CS1039.pdf) and in a even more didactic way [there](https://cglab.ca/%7Ediscmath/relations-introduction.html) at the bottom of the text.
).

As the product of 2 symmetric matrices $R$ and $S$ is  symmetric iff $RS=SR$ (I intentionnaly take the same name for relations and matrices), we are done.

For example, one obtains a counterexample with

$$R=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\
   0&0&1\\
   0&1&1\end{pmatrix};
S=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\
   0&1&0\\
   1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

giving

$$RS=R \odot S=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\
   1&0&0\\
   1&1&0\end{pmatrix} \ \text{and} \ SR=S \odot R=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\
   0&0&1\\
   1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

(none of them being symmetrical).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me understand the question.

Comment: I just added a counterexample.

Comment: That's a great example. Thank you so much.